# How to best dynamically show/hide string segments in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

I'm building a template which may or may not have some values in it; let's say for example I need to build a URL string based on multiple fields coming from a JSON response.

```html
<a class="url">{{ ad.domain }}/{{ ad.path1 }}/{{ ad.path2 }}...</a>
```

But I'm thinking on how to handle that case if some sections of the string are empty; like not having a value for `path2` for example.

I could use an `ng-container` with and `*ngIf` directive inside the anchor tag but it ends up looking really messy and bloated:

```html
<a class="url">{{ ad.domain }}<ng-container *ngIf="ad.path1 !== ''">/{{ ad.path1 }}</ng-container><ng-container *ngIf="ad.path2 !== ''">/{{ ad.path2 }}</ng-container>...</a>
```

It does get the job done, but I'm wondering if there's some other *Angular way* of doing this efficiently.

Comment: Usually, when things are 'bloated', it's time to create a new component. I recently had to do something similar, I ended up creating a custom component with an input array element, then all I have to do is loop with an ngFor directive and it's pretty clean IMO.

Comment: Well, it is a separate component where I'm only displaying information for an ad, the thing is that ads usually have multiple parts, the URL being one that sometimes have different segments, so I'm just trying to control when to display some of those segments

Comment: Please check my initial comment, I updated it.

Comment: It does sound cleaner, but at the same time I'm not sure if creating a component just for this URL thing is too much /: I get what you mean though, I'll think about it

Comment: You can create as many component as you want, just make sure to change the `changeDetection` to `onPush` on such components since their template need to be refreshed only when their input change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **Ternary operator** like this

```
<a class="url">{{ ad.domain+(ad.path1?'/'+ad.path1:'')+(ad.path2?'/'+ad.path2:'') }}</a>
```

Comment: Ohh, that does look a bit better, I actually though of the ternary operator but I always stuck to using multiple interpolation segments ({{}}) instead of one only, I'll try this out